# De-structure an array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I am working with Google Sheets API and I want to de-structure an array of arrays to get the headers and the data. I know that the headers are in `data[0]` and the rest are the row values.

```
var data = [
    ["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"],
    ["data 1.1", "data 1.2", "data 1.3"],
    ["data 2.1", "data 2.2", "data 2.3"],
    ["data 3.1", "data 3.2", "data 3.3"],
    ["data 4.1", "data 4.2", "data 4.3"],
]

var [header, ...rowValues] = [data[0], data]
```

How do it tell that the rest of the arrays should be assigned to the `rowValues`.
I can solve by `rowValues.push()` in a `for` loop that starts on `data[1]` but that would be unelegant.

Comment: Why not `var [header, ...rowValues] = data;`?

Comment: Or use `shift()` to get the first index from the array

Comment: @jabaa's comment should've been the answer ;) it is as succinct as a solution can be.

Comment: Time to stop using `var`.

Comment: @jabaa it worked! yey! thanks! Never had the change to use de-structuring ever since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with

```
const [header, ...rowValues] = data;
```

Comment: It's not like this hasn't been asked and answered ad infinitum.